# solaris lex error

Tags: solaris, lex

Am deploying a lex/yacc solution trying this [grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html).
The problem comes when i want to compile .lex file using this command: lex -t "file.lex"

I get this error:Error: Parse tree too big Try using %e num

Any help please thnks.

Comment: Grammar works fine on Linux with flex 2.5.35. What version of lex are you using? Is it from a pkg, if so which one? Can you install GNU flex?

Comment: Have you actually _tried_ to follow what `lex` is telling you, i.e. simply add an "%e2000" (doubles the parse tree size) to the beginning of the grammar ?

Comment: @MartinCarpenter thnks for the response,in fact this code works good in flex 2.4 in cygwin, but with the solaris doesn't. i checked the version of lex in solaris it said lex SGU solaris elf 4.0.it should be compatible with that. thnkss

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar lex (same output from `lex -V`) and this grammar works fine for me unchanged (Solaris 10/SPARC) so I suspect you may need a patch. `pkginfo` output below.

```
$ pkginfo -l  SUNWbtool 
   PKGINST:  SUNWbtool
      NAME:  CCS tools bundled with SunOS
  CATEGORY:  system
      ARCH:  sparc
   VERSION:  11.10.0,REV=2005.01.21.15.53
   BASEDIR:  /
    VENDOR:  Sun Microsystems, Inc.
      DESC:  software development utilities, including ar, dis, dump, elfdump, lex, lorder, mcs, nm, prof, ranlib, rpcgen, size, strip, tsort, and yacc
    PSTAMP:  on10ptchfeat20090911051613
  INSTDATE:  Mar 15 2011 15:46
   HOTLINE:  Please contact your local service provider
    STATUS:  completely installed
     FILES:       48 installed pathnames
                   8 shared pathnames
                   2 linked files
                   8 directories
                  24 executables
                1874 blocks used (approx)

$
```